# Adding 1 additional object to the map function ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, ecmascript-2016

I have a code in place which looks like this -

```
 mapFn={response => (response.data && response.data.map(secret => ({
                  label: secret.secretName,
                  value: secret.id
                })))}
```

I need to add one more additional object to response.data before it maps and sets it tp mapFn.
So I tried something like -

```
 mapFn={response => (response.data &&
                response.data.append({label: "Select Vault ID", value: "value"})
                && response.data.map(secret => ({
                  label: secret.secretName,
                  value: secret.id
                })))}
```

But I am getting an error as -

```
TS2339: Property 'append' does not exist on type 'SecretSummary[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.data` is an array. Arrays don't have an `.append` method. They do have a `.push` method, but it returns a number, rather than the array (and it mutates, which is forbidden in React). Another issue is that the object you're adding has a `label` and `value` property - which sounds like something that should be added *after* mapping, not before mapping.

Spread the mapped into a new array, and list the object you want to add at the end.

```
mapFn = {
    response => response.data &&
        [
            ...response.data.map(secret => ({
                label: secret.secretName,
                value: secret.id
            })),
            { label: "Select Vault ID", value: "value" }
        ]
}
```

(If you wanted to add the object before mapping, you'd probably want to use the `secretName` and `id` properties when defining the object instead, because otherwise calling the `.map` callback with the object wouldn't make sense.)